# How to prevent making more URL request after an image is already downloaded via Internet?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, async-await

```
var alreadyDdl = false; 
getLogoUrl(context) async {
  if(!alreadyDdl) {
      final db = Localstore.instance;
      final data = db.collection('inputs').doc("1").get();
      var database = (await data)["content"].toString();
      var form = new DGForm("project/getwebsitelogo", {"database": database});
      var ret = await form.urlGET(context);
      ResponseObject responseObject =
      ResponseObject.fromJson(json.decode(ret.body));
      print("hola");
      var hola = (responseObject.datas[0][0].toString());
      bandeauDuClient = hola;
      print(hola);
      return hola;
   }
}
getLogoUrl(context).then((val) {
    setState(() => 
       logoUrl = val
    );
    alreadyDdl = true;
});
```

Will never display me the server downloaded image in the widget build

```
(logoUrl != null) ? Image.network(logoUrl): Image.asset('assets/none.png')
```

And so, when I removed all `alreadyDdl` variables from my code, It will make an http request every 15 miliseconds. I want to stop the http request once the image is really downloaded...

Comment: Post some more code because we can't determine where that code is? If it is in the build method then it will probably call every time a new frame is ready. You should call this function in initState

Comment: Yes, I can confirm, it is in a `Widget build(BuildContext context) {` method, do you need anymore ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a future builder to create widgets based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Future. You can use it in combination with [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package as suggested above.

Here's a sample code that demonstrates so:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
//Your other imports...

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyApp();
  }
}

class _MyApp extends State<MyApp> {
  var db;

  @override
  initState() {
    db = Localstore.instance;
  }

  getLogoUrl(context) async {
    final data = db.collection('inputs').doc("1").get();
    var database = (await data)["content"].toString();
    var form = new DGForm("project/getwebsitelogo", {"database": database});
    var ret = await form.urlGET(context);
    ResponseObject responseObject =
        ResponseObject.fromJson(json.decode(ret.body));
    print("hola");
    var hola = (responseObject.datas[0][0].toString());
    bandeauDuClient = hola;
    print(hola);
    return hola;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getLogoUrl(context),
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // if we got our data
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: snapshot.data,
        progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) => 
                CircularProgressIndicator(value: downloadProgress.progress),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     );
            } else {
              // If we probably got an error check snapshot.hasError
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  '${snapshot.error} occurred',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              );
            }
          } else {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note: Never make networking calls in build method because build method is usually called 60 times per second to render. Make network calls in initState or in widgets like FutureBuilder which handle these things for you.**